# Quiero personalizar un Botón desde el código

Tags: java, botón

Quiero personalizar un bóton y poner un fondo de color rojo, pero al momento de configurar la la tabla declaré las filas como tipo Object, para así declarar desde el código dentro de las celdas botones, pero eso hizo que al momento de querer personalizar estos botones no me lo permita argumentado que no puede convertir datos de tipo Object a Void

```
public void visualizar_Productos(JTable tabla) {
    tabla.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new imgTabla());
    DefaultTableModel dt = new DefaultTableModel() {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    dt.addColumn("Clave");
    dt.addColumn("Producto");
    dt.addColumn("Descripcion");
    dt.addColumn("Precio");
    dt.addColumn("Eliminar");
    dt.addColumn("Modificar");

    BD mBD = new BD();
    Productos vo = new Productos();
    ArrayList<Productos> list = mBD.Listar_Productos();

    if (list.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Object fila[] = new Object[7];

            vo = list.get(i);
            fila[0] = vo.getClave();
            fila[1] = vo.getNombre();
            fila[2] = vo.getDesc();
            fila[3] = vo.getPrecio();

            ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(get_Image("trash.jpg"));
            if (get_Image("trash.jpg") != null) {
                icono = new ImageIcon(get_Image("trash.jpg").getScaledInstance(20,20,20));
            }

            if (icono == null) {
                fila[4] = new JButton("eliminar");
                fila[4] = new JButton("eliminar");
            } else {
                fila[4] = new JButton(icono).setBackground(java.awt.Color.RED);

            }


            fila[5] = new JButton("Modificar");

            dt.addRow(fila);
        }
        tabla.setModel(dt);
        tabla.setRowHeight(32);
    }
}
```

Comment: En qué linea lanza el error?

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es el tipo `Object` del arreglo, el problema es que el método  `setBackground()` retorna `void` y lo que estás haciendo ahí es intentar asignarle ese `void` a un arreglo que espera un `Object`

En este caso debes hacerlo por separado, reemplaza el `else` que tienes con este:

```
else {
    JButton boton = new JButton(icono);
    boton.setBackground(java.awt.Color.RED);

    fila[4] = boton;
}
```

En otras palabras, primero se crea el botón, luego se asigna su color y al final se agrega al arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo en mis JFrames, en su main a veces pongo:

```
miClaseHerederaJFrame miJFrame = new miClaseHerederaJFrame().setVisible(true);
```

y me funciona. Crea el frame y lo pone en visible true y lo visualiza.

Lo cierto es que yo no entiendo por qué este código no funciona bien.

En cualquier caso, siempre se puede hacer en 2 líneas, en vez de 1.

```
Fila[4]=new JButton(icono);
Fila[4].setBackGround(java.awt.Color.RED);
```

Y me da que así si es más posible que funcione.